# Смещение подписей трехмерного графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

Я строю трехмерную визуализацию по [датасету](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zh6cPoWkIsAnmXnySEPM-K5O48vzcqph/view?usp=sharing) и в ней подписи шкал 'disk', 'year' и 'price' накладываются на градуировки шкал.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # для отрисовки 3D проекции
%matplotlib inline

matplotlib.rc("font", size=18) # для увеличения шрифта подписей графиков
phones = pd.read_csv('1.8_phones.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=None) 
phones.drop(phones.index[0],  inplace=True)
phones.rename(columns={0: 'disk', 1: 'os', 2: 'price', 3: 'year'}, inplace=True)
phones['disk'] = phones['disk'].astype(int)
phones['price'] = phones['price'].astype(int)
phones['year'] = phones['year'].astype(int)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = phones[['disk']]
y = phones['price']
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
[b] = reg.coef_
a = reg.intercept_
def reg_prediction(disk):
    return a + b * disk
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8)) # создаем картинку
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d") # устанавливаем проекцию

# помещаем точки на график
ax.scatter(phones["disk"], phones["year"], phones["price"], s=100)
plt.title('Зависимость цены телефона от памяти и года выпуска', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_xlabel("disk", loc='right')
ax.set_ylabel("year")
ax.set_zlabel("price")
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо отодвинуть подписи шкал от их градуировки, чтобы они не заходили друг на друга. [Установки позиции подписей с помощью loc='right/left'](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_labels_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-axis-labels-demo-py) не помогли.

Comment: `labelpad=15` вроде помогает, но не для оси `z`, по ней тогда подпись за картинку вылазит. Нужно мне кажется размер фонта уменьшить для подписей на осях

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ax.set_xlabel("disk", loc='right', labelpad = 20.)
ax.set_ylabel("year", labelpad = 40.)
ax.set_zlabel("price", labelpad = 60.)
```

И результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот странно, в `Google Colab` на параметр `loc=` ругается, что нет такого и `price` за границу картинки выезжает. Там версия что ли старая...